# Magento PHP Extension "gd" must be loaded problem

Tags: php, apache-2.2, magento

I am on Ubuntu 9.10 & I am trying to install Magento but I am getting this error

I have aleady installed gd (sudo apt-get install php5-gd)
But I am still getting this error & yes I have restarted the apache server a couple of times but still no use....

any idea ...?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your php.ini to see if GD is being loaded?

Answer (score 1):

If your phpinfo page (`<? phpinfo(); ?>`) doesn't show GD as being loaded then it's not actually in use. Remember that you have to restart your webserver to activate changes to your php configuration.

Answer (score 0):

look at the apache modules, mine is at /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-gd.ini

```
; configuration for php GD module
; priority=20
; extension=gd.so
```

Even if the module exists and is installed on the system, it is commented out on the module config. Uncomment it, then restart Apache, then you should be fine.